# Orange 3 is not launching

Tags: data-mining, orange

My orange 3 doesn't launch and through the following error,
AttributeError: module 'PyQt5.QtCore' has no attribute 'Signal'
please let me know how to resolve this. Python version 3.7, anaconda nevigator version 4.11.0

Answer (score 0):

In Anaconda command prompt run

```
pip install orange3
```

This should show the dependency, and that the you have the wrong version of PyQt5 along with which version you need. My experience with Orange3 so far is that the PyQt5 version I have is too high (find the version list here https://pypi.org/project/PyQt5/) . Install the correct version with

```
pip install PyQt5=={version number}
```

That should correct the issue